# How to show Google Maps with address in angular2

Tags: google-maps, angular, geocoding, google-maps-api-2

I could success to show google map using lat and lng.
However, I have no idea how to show it using address.
**I mean I need to generate lat & lng from address.**

I saw some codes here, mostly using google.maps.Geocoder.
**The problem is that if I try to use google.maps.Geocoder, it makes an error that cannot find name 'google'.**

If anyone know how to solve this problem, please let me know.
And if you reply with example code, it could big help!

Thanks for your help and advice! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
npm install --save @types/googlemaps;

import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
```

to your component.ts file

It's work for me!

Comment: The guy who asked the question answered it himself. Doesn't make sense to write another answer..

Comment: @Ray it absolutely makes sense to post new answers, in order to both benefit other users who may have the same question but be dissatisfied with the accepted answer, and to offer an alternative solution for the OP to consider.

Answer (score 4):

It was simple. I solve this that call api url with address parameter

```
constructor(private http: Http) { }
  getlatlng(address){
    return this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address)
      .catch(handleError);
  }
```

Comment: This, unfortunately gives a Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Comment: Geocoding API costs $5.00 per 1,000 calls, or $0.005 per call :(

Answer (score 2):

This is a really good tutorial for searching an address and displaying it on google maps:

http://brianflove.com/2016/10/18/angular-2-google-maps-places-autocomplete/

It has a plunkr demo as well at the bottom. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Address to Lat & long

```
let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

//verify result
if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
    return
}

//set latitude, longitude
this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's not for mine.
I know how to get address from lat&lng.
I need to know how to get lat & lng from address.

Comment: I added a code snippet above where he converts the address entered (place) into lat & long. Is this what you were looking to do?

Answer (score 0):

I installed again using `npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev`
So, I could solve the error that `cannot find name 'google'`

And... Are there anyone give me some example geocoding with angular2?

Answer (score -1):

to find the name as google in your application you need to declare the 
`var google : any ;` at the top component.